# Cannot see my images resources launching J2EE preview

Tags: eclipse, image, jakarta-ee, preview, wicket-1.6

I am working with wicket framework and I'm pretty new in Java.

I'm trying to format my website, and if I open my homepage as static (just opening as Html page) the browser show all the styles and images. But when I try to run it on j2EE preview it renders the styles from the link tag but not the images defined inside of the css file. They can't be shown.

I checked the Java Build Path and the folder /resources/images are there. But when I try to see the image putting the absolute path ( and right path) directly in the browser it shows "not found".

Should I configure something else? or should respect some folders hierarchy of wicket to make it done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are the images references in the CSS file(s)? Where in the project structure are the CSS files? You may want to read http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/6.x/guide/resources.html

Comment: Hi Martin , 

I found it out. It happened for me for 2 reasons:
   1 - Wicket has to get know that my css file is a resource if I have it into a class path folder. So I added the tag < wicket:link > and wicket could render my styles.
   2 - The images should be resources for Wicket as well.  So a added the images in Wicket/resources then would render the images properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Wicket has to get know that my css file is a resource if I have it into a class path folder. So I added the tag < wicket:link > and wicket could render my styles.

2 - The images should be resources for Wicket as well. So a added the images in Wicket/resources then would render the images properly.

It is working now although it would exist another way to do the same.